# How to find all the php files under current directory and add a line

Tags: unix, command-line, terminal

How do you do that in terminal or anywhere else?

`echo "//test comment" > find . -type f -name "*.js"`

doesn't work. I just want to add a line on top of each .js files. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "//test comment" > myline
for file in *.js; do
  cp myline dummy
  cat $file >> dummy
  cp dummy $file
done
```

or:

```
#!/bin/bash
for file in *.js; do
  sed -i '1i //test comment' $file
done
```

Comment: You might need to edit the first line that points to bash, I have no idea what it is in mac OS.

Comment: it only created a *.js file :(

Comment: Hmm, must be a mac OS thing, try to replace *.js with $(ls *.js)

Answer (score -1):

Try something like this:

```
find . -type f -name "*.js" -exec echo >> {} \;
```

Comment: that only created a {} file...:(